# Simpliest MySQL WHERE Optional. How?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following snippet **shows a SELECT query on all records from a table**.

**As you can see,** I have commented out the WHERE clause and the PDO Binding corresponding to it.

```
# CREATE PDO CONNECTION
$pdoConnection = self::pdoConnection();

# ESTIMATE QUERY STRING...
$pdoQueryString = "
                  SELECT *
                  FROM
                    tblEstimate
                  -- WHERE status = :estimatesFilter
                  LIMIT 5;

                  ";

# PREPARE...
$pdoStatement = self::pdoStatement($pdoConnection, $pdoQueryString);
# BIND...
// $pdoStatement->bindParam(":estimatesFilter", $estimatesFilter, PDO::PARAM_STR); // STR
# EXECUTE...
$pdoStatement->execute();
# FETCH ALL...
$pdoResultSet = $pdoStatement->fetchAll();
```

**I understand I can do string concatenation using if conditions to achieve this but**, is there a "classier" way to do it?

Other thoughts

I've read about MySQL's COALESCE function but not enough to know if it's only available for stored procedures as I seem to keep running into.

Comment: To change the SHAPE of a query, dynamic SQL must be employed (eg. string concatenation of some sort). However, if the condition fits in the same SHAPE, it is possible to write like: “.. WHERE :x IS NULL OR :x = COL..” (example; where the condition is only ‘applied’ when a value is given for x). More advanced variations can be written with CASE. Remember to keep an eye on query plans.

Comment: Also, even with string concatenation to build a query, values should *still be applied with parameter bindings*. This keeps the generated query cleaner and still avoids SQL injection if written correctly.

Comment: Can you kindly comment on the COALESCE function if it relates to this question? Still intrigued by it.

Comment: I am curious about what you are asking; are you asking about `IF` and `COALESCE` as they relate to SQL or are you asking about building dynamic queries?  If you are asking about the latter, you can use any "query builder" to accomplish this cleanly.

Comment: As they relate to this question. Can I use it instead of concatenation? Reference to doing this entirely in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, any query builder can be used to avoid ugly string concatenation of queries.  I help maintain a little standalone query builder called [FaaPz/PDO](https://github.com/FaaPz/PDO) (but any query builder will do).  It is basically an Object Oriented representation of the query, where you can dynamically add parts to it.  Here is some documentation for the laravel [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) for comparison.  Ex: `$user = DB::table('users'); if (true) { $user->where('name', 'John'); } $record = $user->first();`

Comment: THAT, is really cool. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Alex.